# Error on a simple https get test

Tags: java, rest, https

I'm following the mkyong tutorial from https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restfull-java-client-with-java-net-url/
But instead of calling localhost, I'm using this website: https://httpbin.org/get

I was able to make it work with HTTP, but not with HTTPS. When I try to run it with HTTPS, I get this error:

```
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderExce
ption: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source
)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect
(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown S
ource)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown So
urce)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unk
nown Source)
        at com.my.app.HTTPSGetTest.main(HTTPSGetTest.java:22)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
 sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find vali
d certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Sour
ce)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
 find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Sourc
e)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown
 Source)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
        ... 21 more
```

Here is the code I'm using:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class HTTPSGetTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

      URL url = new URL("https://httpbin.org/get");
      HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
      conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

      if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + conn.getResponseCode());
      }

      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));

      String output;
      System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
      while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(output);
      }

      conn.disconnect();

    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {

      e.printStackTrace();

    }
    catch (IOException e) {

      e.printStackTrace();

    }

  }
}
```

I tried running InstallCert.java like described here: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target/, but I get the following error doing that:

```
Loading KeyStore C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31\lib\security\cacerts...
Opening connection to localhost:3128...
Starting SSL handshake...
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source
)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
        at InstallCert.main(InstallCert.java:105)
```

I'm behind a proxy and I'm using cntlm to access things outside the proxy. I don't know if this is the problem, or something else, since I was able to do the request without problems using HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the steps mentioned here [www.grim.se/guide/jre-cert](https://www.grim.se/guide/jre-cert)

Also, confirm if you have followed the steps mentioned here [how-to-configure-tomcat-to-support-ssl-or-https](http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-configure-tomcat-to-support-ssl-or-https/)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: @SteveSmith I did go through the links I have posted and it does seem that it will help the asker. Thanks for comment though. Good to know :)